# jinja2 load template file from template

Tags: jinja2

Is there a way I can load a jinja2 template from within another template file? Something like

```
{{ render_template('path/to/file.html') }}
```

I have some snippets which I want to reuse, so it's important for me to have this functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use either the `extends` tag or the `include` tag, depending on how you want to design your multi-file views.

Answer (score 56):

`{% include "file" %}` does this. See the [jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include) for more information.

Comment: I read the docs and cannot find a way to pass `template params` to `include` call. May you clarify if it is possible?

Comment: @NamGVU I'm not sure this is the best approach but for one template I use a nested template twice via the include mechanism to populate two instances in the same template. Before the include I define a set of flask variables to serve as formal variables to the subtemplate. The values of those variables serve as actual arguments to the subtemplate, and they are populated according to the context of the parent template that I'm creating.

Comment: Check my answer for a way to do this cleanly.

Comment: Can I also use this statement to include a css file into the `<style>` tag inside an html file?

Answer (score 12):

You should make template files with `{% macro -%}`s and use `{% import "file" as file %}` to use the macros in other template files. See [the docs.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#macros)

Here is an example:

```
<!- in common_macros.html ->
{% macro common_idiom1(var1, var2, ... varN) -%}
    <!- your idiom, where you can use var1 through varN ->
{%- endmacro %}
<!- in my_template.html ->
{% import "common_macros.html" as idioms %}
{{ idioms.common_idiom1(a, b, ... N) }}
```

Specifically this answer allows the OP to pass arguments to his macros, similar to the behavior he desired like how render_template behaves (simply including the file as previous answers have stated above does not achieve the same behavior as render_template).

This is generally better than making a fresh template for every idiom, or than using inheritance, which is a special case solution (what if you want to use the snippet multiple times in one template)?

Comment: Upon re-reading OP's question I'm realizing that the question I had when I stumbled on this page was not exactly the same question OP had. That said, it is a poorly scaling practice to make a new template file for every idiom, like the other answer advised. Using inheritance is a special case solution only. So I think it is good that I posted, for future readers (like I just was).