# How do I inject a template into another template in Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2

kind of a novice question here and I apologize if it's already been answered, but I couldn't seem to find anything that didn't relate to Django rather than Flask.

So I know all about {% extends %} statements and how they are used to load template components from other HTML documents. But I want to be able to do it without refreshing a page or calling another view function.

essentially I have various absolutely positioned forms that edit aspects of the main page (which displays a non-profit's DB.)

I need to be able to load the forms into the home / base template without a refresh, then subsequently reload the  and reinterpolate its contents without reloading the page.

I am already using AJAX to pass the form's data to the backend asynchronously, so I have what I need to call whatever functions I have to build up, but I'm in the dark as to the next step.

again, sorry if this has been covered, and for the lack of brevity. Let me know if there's any code you need to see that would be particularly relevant.

Comment: Have you checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7337814/15368978)?

Comment: You are looking for something like the [HTMX framework](https://htmx.org/). With this you can call your backend and replace parts of the page without a full refresh. It's just a JS framework, but it makes this type of interactivity very easy with Flask/Django (or any other backend framework).

Comment: oh thanks Patrick, and Dauros. I feel a bit foolish for having missed that thread, but it's looking like the solution is much simpler than I was anticipating.

and that HTMX thing looks insane. hell of a lot of applications beyond what I am thinking right now.

Comment: Templates run on the server. Make your AJAX request and set `.innerHTML`/`.innerText` or append a DOM node to inject the data into the document. Usually, send the raw data (as JSON) and let the client build the HTML (a la Single Page App), but you can also respond with HTML chunks, optionally running jinja2 on them. If you try searching "flask update data without page refresh" you shouldn't see any Django stuff.

Comment: alright I didn't expect to get so many workable solutions so quickly, so thanks everyone on really giving me a vote of confidence on this community in general. I think I have everything I need at this point so I'm going to mark the question as answered. again, y'all are awesome.